# PHP error handler function or class?

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging

I'm getting close to taking a PHP application live and so I know that I need to disable error reporting (to hide errors from users) and instead log the errors.

I found the `set_error_handler` function in the PHP docs and there is an example shown, but I'm wondering if there is any kind of standard error handler function (to be set as the callback in `set_error_handler`) or class that is typically used by PHP developers to log errors?

If there isn't a function or class that is considered "standard," would you show your error handling function?

Comment: http://perishablepress.com/how-to-enable-php-error-logging-via-htaccess/

Comment: I understand that you probably don't want an error to display in your software on your server. But please don't try to change the server settings (i.e. ini_set) of other peoples servers. You are better off writing your code to not throw silly errors like notice/warnings and verbosely check values for expected results (i.e. check if is_array before a foreach if there is even a small chance it isn't an array and you "know" it will be...etc). Changing server settings is a quick way to get deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to make changes to the php.ini file to turn on-screen error reporting off but error logging on:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL &~E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set("error_log", "error.log");
```

Answer (score 1):

error_log — Send an error message to the defined error handling routines

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

http://www.stanford.edu/dept/its/communications/webservices/wiki/index.php/How_to_perform_error_handling_in_PHP